# is there windows media player in Windows 8 Enterprise N

Tags: windows-8, media-player

I have installed my laptop with windows 8 Enterprise N, but windows media player didn't installed with the operating system, i have repeated this two times but there is not. does the windows media player included in windows 8 enterprise N?

Answer (score 3):

[What's an N edition of Windows?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-to-n) (Emphasis mine)

> **N editions of Windows 8.1 and Windows 8 don't include** media-related technologies like **Windows Media Player or Camera**. To play or create audio CDs, digital media files, and video DVDs; organize content in a media library; create playlists; convert audio CDs to digital media files; view artist and title information of digital media files; view album art of music files; transfer music to personal music players; or record and play back TV broadcasts after Windows 8.1 or Windows 8 is installed, you'll need to install a media player and other software from Microsoft or another company.
>
> **Internet Explorer 11 in N editions of Windows 8.1 doesn’t include** media features like **adaptive streaming or Digital Rights Management** (DRM) playback. To add these features, you’ll need to download and install the Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows from the Microsoft Download Center, as well as an app that uses PlayReady DRM from the Windows Store, such as the Xbox Music app or Xbox Video app. The app must be installed to specifically turn on DRM features, while all other media features are installed with the Media Feature Pack.

So that’s a no. There is no WMP in N editions of Windows. That’s the point, after all.

Answer (score 0):

As *Daniel B* said, the N Edition come without the Media Player, but Microsoft offers an Update to restore the Media Player:

**Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30685

If you use a 32Bit Windows, download the Windows6.2-KB2703761-x86.msu, otherwise the Windows6.2-KB2703761-x64.msu and make a double click on the MSU file to install it.